# How to stop a program compiled with MinGW (g++) from opening a console window in windows

Tags: windows, g++, mingw

I compiled a program using MinGW g++. When I run it, it opens a console window in addition to the main application window. What's the compiler flag to stop this?

Comment: To compare the 2 answers given below, see [this informative post at the GCC mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-01/msg00225.html)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe the compiler switch for that is `-Wl,-subsystem,windows`.

The `-Wl,<options>` switch passes `<options>` to the linker. The `-subsystem` switch tells the linker which system to target when generating the executable.

Answer (score 58):

I just add `-mwindows` to linker flags.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Only `-Wl,-subsystem,windows` did.

Comment: This worked for me, however (using MinGW on Mac from Homebrew).