# How to hide console window on Windows when using scons-qt4 plugin?

Tags: python, qt, scons

When I'm building on Windows with scons-qt4 plugin, my application always opens a console window, even though it has its own windows. With QMake, you could force application to do the same by adding CONFIG += console or something similar, but the default behaviour is to suppress it. QMake can handle it - I'm sure scons can, too.

The only way I see so far to solve this problem would be to use #ifdef around int main():

```
#ifdef WIN32
int WinMain (int _argc, char **_argv)
#else
int main (int _argc, char **_argv)
#endif
```

But that's just abominable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems, my question was almost already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441551/how-to-stop-mingw-g-opening-a-console-window-in-windows). Now, applied to scons, these two lines did it for me:

```
if (env ['PLATFORM'] == 'win32'):
    env.Append (LINKFLAGS = ['-Wl,-subsystem,windows'])
```

Also, kind thanks to the folks on the [scons-users] mailing list. In particular, David Van Maren pointed out that:

> You might look for whether you are
>   linking against the qtmain library.
>   The latest Qt documentation only says
>   this about it:
>
> --------------- The qtmain Library
>
> qtmain is a helper library that
>   enables the developer to write a
>   cross-platform main() function on
>   Windows and on the Symbian platform.
>   If you do not use qmake or other build
>   tools such as CMake, then you need to
>   link against theqtmain library.
>
> ---
>
> It may not be related, but I *think*
>   that once I added it to the link, the
>   bogus console disappeared for our Qt
>   gui applications.

This may be another way to solve the problem, for example, when program is compiled with other tools than GCC + MinGW.