# C++ compiler questions

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I was just wondering how C++ compilers deal with certain things:
First, how do I find out which C++ compiler I have? (gcc? gnu? or something...)
Then, how does the compiler hide the console window when I'm programming a windows gui?
(or is hiding the console done in code?)
Also, how do I include dlls when compiling?
And is there any place I could learn everything else about my compiler?

EDIT: @StuartGolodetz I think I have minGW, actually (I'm using DevCpp); and what I meant when I asked how to hide the console window or how to include dlls is not how to set it up in the IDE I'm using, but rather, how do I do it *at the command line?*

Comment: You don't have to have a console for every program.

Comment: As a side point, there's no point getting irritated by people's answers when they're trying to help you - you've asked a multi-part question with lots of unrelated parts (which is ill-suited to the StackOverflow format), and I gave up some of my time to try and answer it.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to come out that way. I suppose I'm just a little tired, and looking for a solid answer.

Comment: @AUTO: No worries, was just trying to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult question to answer, because you might have many different compilers on your system, and it's really a question of which one you're *using* :) That said, `gcc`/`g++` is a common compiler on UNIX-based systems, and `Visual C++` is a common compiler on Windows - there's a reasonable chance you'll be using one of those.

If you're on a UNIX-based system and you want to find out if you've got `g++`, say, you can do:

```
which g++
```

To find out which version (if you've got it), do:

```
g++ --version
```

---

In terms of Visual C++ hiding the console window when you're programming a Windows GUI, it just doesn't show it if you've set the subsystem to Windows in your project settings.

---

You don't include DLLs when compiling, you link against the `.lib` file corresponding to them and then make sure they can be found at run-time. Note the (important) distinction between compilation and linking. This seems like a reasonable link:

http://edmulroy.portbridge.com/oview.htm

---

Assuming your compiler is Visual C++ (which is what it sounds like), you can just read through MSDN.

---

EDIT:

In response to your new question, see here:

[How to stop Mingw (g++) opening a console window in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441551/how-to-stop-mingw-g-opening-a-console-window-in-windows)

Re. DLLs, you don't include them - you link against the import library for the DLL using `-l<libname>` and then make sure the DLL itself is either in the same directory as the executable or on the system path at runtime.

Comment: Read through MSDN? But that would take them years!

Comment: @MrLister: "can" != "should" :) The real answer is that you learn about your compiler empirically, by trying things out - but that will also take a long time. Gaining experience is a slow process, unfortunately.

Comment: @StuartGolodez True, but if you're unsure of what you're looking for (e.g. what it's called exactly), MSDN is just too big to be handy.