# G++ how to compile a program that doesn't open the console. It has to be multiplatform, not just for Windows.?

Tags: c++, command-line, compilation, g++, codeblocks

I'm running G++ (mingw tdm, I think) from the command line, and I'm trying to make a program that doesn't open the command prompt/terminal.

I know it's possible: in [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)I can just use the project's properties and set it to 'GUI Application', but I have no idea what flag to use with g++.

If I can't fix it I'll just go back to using CodeBlocks, but prefer like using NotePad++ with G++. If it somehow is not possible why and then how does Code::Blocks do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Mingw (g++) opening a console window in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441551/how-to-stop-mingw-g-opening-a-console-window-in-windows)

Comment: Note that the console/GUI difference only applies to Windows. On Unix-y systems, a program can always access both (provided, of course, a graphic server is available otherwise it can only access the console) and never opens a new console by itself, it just reuses the current console if any or silently runs in the background otherwise.

Comment: @syam
It's not a duplicate of that other question, I read all the awnsers there yesterday (before I asked this question, and even before I made this account, I think) and non of it seemed to awnser my question. But maybe I'm just stupid. And because I'm on windows it should really be enough to use the windows stuff, I just don't really like having to use platform-dependent things. I'll just use the -mwindows flag like that other question suggested.
If I made it look like I didn't appreseate (I'm not English, I don't know how to spel that) your awnser, I'm sorry, thanks anyway.

Comment: What I meant is: despite what you asked, your question only applies to Windows executables. This problem doesn't even exist on other OSes (they work differently and never open a console without the user explicitly asking for it first), so there can be no multiplatform solution for an issue that exists only on one platform. And once you realize that, your question becomes a duplicate of the one I linked. Hope I was more clear this time, I'm not a native English speaker either so I realize my explanations can sometimes be confusing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add "-mwindows" to your linker options.
I'm not 100% sure if this works on other OS's than windows, you just gotta try it.

Comment: Reference to some source that explains this flag would be useful

Comment: Yeah I guess I'm on windows anyway, I'll just do that... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> [-mwindows](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Windows-Options.html): This option is available for Cygwin and MinGW targets.
>   It specifies that a GUI application is to be generated by instructing
>   the linker to set the PE header subsystem type appropriately.

So yeah, this flag will only work on Windows.

After some programming I noticed that on Linux there is no standard I/O console at all.
This means you will get console I/O only when you run your program via the console ( *./MyProgram* ). Now that's convenient.