# How to hide console window in Win32 API C?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to hide the annoying console window which appears in GUI c programs while running.
For example, if I compile the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI
WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR pszCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world", "My program", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return 0;
}
```

it will show a console window while running the program. Any help will be appreciated....
Thank you in advance....

Comment: Check the `/Subsystem` in Linker

Answer (score 0):

Use `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` in the `link` step.  Are you using Visual Studio and building a Console application?  If you choose Windows Application it will use the right linker switch.

Comment: I am using CodeBlocks and I am trying to learn Win32 API GUI programing in C.

Comment: I am just using a simple mingw32 c compiler to compile the application and if I add    /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS code to it, it shows error. can you give a demo of what are you talking exactly @ Mark Tolonen

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4441551/235698) will help.  The mingw linker uses a different syntax.