# Cross compile with i686-w64-mingw32-g++ and use main() as entry point

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, program-entry-point, mingw-w64, winmain

I am compiling for Linux in a make target using plain `g++` for my linux executable and for windows in a separate make target using `i686-w64-mingw32-g++`. If I use main(), the g++ target builds and the windows target fails with:

`` ./build/i686-w64-mingw32-i686-w64-mingw32-crt/./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain@16' ``

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441551/how-to-stop-a-program-compiled-with-mingw-g-from-opening-a-console-window-in)

I tried the two solutions from the link above, but neither worked.

Here is my windows build target:

`RayCaster1.cpp SDLWrapper.cpp -I/usr/local/i686-w64-mingw32/include -L/usr/local/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic -o testWindows.exe`

Adding -mwindows or -Wl,-subsystem,windows did not solve the problem for me. I tried putting one of them at a time at the end, beginning, middle. My windows build target has become really bloated, am I borking it with another flag?

Here is my main function:

```
int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    SDLWrapper sdlWrapper;

    initRasterPixels();
    sdlWrapper.setupSDLRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, generateRaster);
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Do you actually have a `main` function? It would improve the question to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the exact build command

Comment: Generally you should not be putting those include and library paths; if the compiler was installed properly it would search there by default (but maybe you have a peculiar installation)

Comment: Yes I have a function like this: int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])

If I change it to WinMain, then my windows make target works and I have a windows executable

Comment: also you should not be using `-mwindows`, that means to look for WinMain

Comment: @M.M I probably need to modify my path to simplify my build command, I was just happy to get cross compilation to work at all. My linux build target is much shorter and cleaner, just `g++ RayCaster1.cpp SDLWrapper.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -o test.exe`

Comment: perhaps there is a problem with your compiler installation then . You should be able to use the same build command you just posted, but with the different location of g++. Also you could eliminate some factors by building `int main() { return 0; }` and `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ foo.cpp` with no other switches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-mconsole` instead of `-mwindows`.